# Mount Windows share is read-only for one user and writeable for another!

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have shared a folder in Windows 10 and mounted the share in Ubuntu 22.04 via fstab with the following setting:

```
//192.168.xxx.xx/b/MySharedFolder /media/Share cifs vers=3.0,defaults,rw,credentials=/root/.pass
```

Evidently, the file in /root/.pass contains the credentials for the Windows share. The strange thing is that for a user johndoe@hotmail.com in that file, I have write access to the mounted location from within Ubuntu. For another user, of which I will call SomeUser, the mounted location is read only! Both of these users are given full permissions in Windows, although johndoe@hotmail.com is a Windows administrator. I did change the account of SomeUser to administrator but that didn't change things.

Alternatively, this has write access:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=johndoe@hotmail.com,password=somepassword //192.168.xxx.xx/b/MySharedFolder /media/Share
```

but this does not:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=SomeUser,password=somepassword //192.168.xxx.xx/b/MySharedFolder /media/Share
```

I would be grateful for anyone who can point out the cause of my issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's curious about your description is no one but root should have write access to the mounted share because you didn't provide an override to the default.

If you want any user on the client machine to have write access to the mounted share something like this would be better:

```
//192.168.xxx.xx/b/MySharedFolder /media/Share cifs vers=3.0,defaults,rw,credentials=/root/.pass,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666,nounix
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately, that didn't achieve the desired results. The situation is still the same with one user having write access and the other read-only access. I can't help but think that this is a Windows issue. On a separate Windows machine, both users can be used to authenticate to the shared location with write access. I just can't figure out what the issue is in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to gain some success. JohnDoe has been given write permission to `//192.168.xxx.xx/b/MySharedFolder` in Windows but the Linux mount using his credentials were read-only.

To enable writing, I went back to Windows, added JohnDoe as a Shared User at the root, i.e. `//192.168.xxx.xx/b/` and in the location `//192.168.xxx.xx/b/MySharedFolder`, I enabled inheritance.

This is not ideal since JohnDoe has read access to all subfolders of `//192.168.xxx.xx/b/` but I think I can sort that one out.

Answer (score 0):

If above command works well under root, then try add this

```
-o username=johndoe@hotmail.com,password=somepassword,vers=3.0,defaults,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666,nounix
```

If it doesn't work under root then check sharing permission in Windows 10x.